# How to change View background/foreground to a specific pattern?

Tags: android, drawable, foreground

So I'm making a simple snake game in android. For the board I'm using a gridlayout with TextViews, which I simply change the background color in if the snake reaches that TextView. Very simple!

Now I want to change the views so they get a certain pattern if the snake reach them. I've unsuccessfully tried several ways, but I think the best way would be to put a foreground in the view.

I'm currently trying

```
TextView tempHead = (TextView) grid.getChildAt(headIndex);
tempHead.setBackgroundColor(snakeColor);
tempHead.setForeground(...);
```

`tempHead.setForeground()` accepts `"android.graphics.drawable.Drawable foreground"`

Drawable is abstract, and I don't know what subclass is best to make my own pattern (and is it best to do in XML, programmatically or maybe a picture?)

So basicaly my question is: how can I make my own pattern as a Drawable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own class extending from `Drawable` and override desired methods